# Cannot install any theme

Tags: 8, installation

I am new to Drupal and am facing an issue where any theme that I try to install will fail with the following message:

```
Installing light_skeleton
An error has occurred.
Please continue to the error page

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 403
Debugging information follows.
Path: /core/authorize.php/core/authorize.php?batch=1&id=4&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: Forbidden
ResponseText: 
403 Forbidden
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.9.10
```

The root folder is owned by `www-data:www-data` and I have given the directory 775 permissions. I have also tried to give it a full access using `chmod 777` but without success.

I have checked the logs of nginx and php but there are no errors displayed. The site itself, using the standard theme, works without any issues.

After getting the error, I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: log in update_authorize_install_batch_finished() (line 291 of core/modules/update/update.authorize.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in update_authorize_install_batch_finished() (line 291 of core/modules/update/update.authorize.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: log in update_authorize_install_batch_finished() (line 332 of core/modules/update/update.authorize.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: tasks in update_authorize_install_batch_finished() (line 333 of core/modules/update/update.authorize.inc).
Installation failed! See the log below for more information.
```

Comment: I get you are trying to upload a theme from the site.

Comment: Yes. Choosing the downloaded theme, and clicking install new theme, and selecting the file

Comment: I have the same problem with modules. Check admin/reports/dblog and see if you get errors about `ini_set()` being disabled. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Didn't find any ref to `ini_set()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an nginx configuration issue and discussed intensely on [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2583799) Yet curiously no solid solution could be offered. Some guy on an other page proposed a [solution](https://pantheon.io/blog/update-your-nginx-config-drupal-8#comment-2418321470). I applied that proposed solution and can confirm that in works!

To apply proposed solution go to your nginx [configuration](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/) file under

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/** directory on Ubuntu and add

```
rewrite ^/core/authorize.php/core/authorize.php(.*)$ /core/authorize.php$1;
```

**just above the**

```
location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
}
```

block. Location does matter!.. Restart your server:

> sudo service nginx restart

and that's it. The problem solved!

Comment: That works! It's a shame that Drupal 8 seems needs that workaround with nginx!

Comment: This is the only answer I have found that immediately resolves the issue for me. I am a bit disappointed that this is still an issue in Drupal 9.1.5. even though it appears to have been discussed, ad nauseum, on Drupal forums and elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are getting a 403 response, it seems that Drupal is not giving you access for some reason. I haven't had any practical experience with this, but looking in the `authorize.php`, file I found this:

```
function authorize_access_allowed(Request $request) {
  $account = \Drupal::service('authentication')->authenticate($request);
  if ($account) {
    \Drupal::currentUser()->setAccount($account);
  }
  return Settings::get('allow_authorize_operations', TRUE) && \Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer software updates');
}
```

It seems that you could get an access denied response if:

- You don't have `administer software updates` permission.
- `allow_authorize_operations` is set to false. This would exist in your `settings.php` file AS `$settings['allow_authorize_operations'] = FALSE;`

Best guess is that it's the latter that might be your problem.

Comment: Tried both solutions but with no luck. I am the admin of the site as I have it on my own vps.

Comment: Its good option to update settings.php rather than updaing ngnix conf, If it doesn't solve can try      updating:  $settings['update_free_access'] = FALSE;// Update it to TRUE

Answer (score -2):

I have similar error, any solution? 
update i just finally fixed it
just add this:
rewrite ^/core/authorize.php/core/authorize.php(.*)$ /core/authorize.php$1;
to my server{} block of my nginx conf